# Generar nuevas variables a partir de información de tipo carácter en otra variable

Tags: r

Tengo una variable tipo carácter con categorias de respuesta (var1). Cada opción sigue una misma estructura pero la cantidad de opciones de cada respondiente puede ser diferente (entre 1 y 6). Necesito que cada opción de respuesta sea una nueva variable que con valor 1 si marco la opción, 0 si no marco esa opción pero tiene alguna respuesta y NA si no respondió nada.

Probé con "str_detect" pero para casi todos los casos que tienen valor (sea 1 o 6 categorias= me pone TRUE, no logro que solo indique TRUE cuando es la categoria que quiero aislar.

```
df$var_1<-str_detect(df$var1,"[a.XXX])")

data frame actual:
1 [a.XXX],[b.XXX], [c.XXX]
2 [c.XXX],[h.XXX]
3 [a.XXX],[b.XXX], [d.XXX], [g.XXX]
4 NA
```

Comment: Hola @MVC. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Creo que tu pregunta podría dar un poco más de información a quien quiera ayudarte (ayudanos a ayudarte). Para alguien que no está en tu lugar, la pregunta da muy poco contexto. En particular en tu caso no entiendo tus datos nos ayudaría que compartieras una muestra simulada de tus datos reales. Por ejemplo has un head(df) y compártelo, puedes cambiar los valores por otros distintos pero conserva el formato. Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de esto, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0):

MVC entiendo el último fragmentó de código que   compartes es el contenido de tu variable `var1` de tu `data.frame` por lo que tus datos se leerían así.

```
df<-read.table(text= 'var1
    "[a.XXX],[b.XXX],[c.XXX]"
    "[c.XXX],[h.XXX]"
    "[a.XXX],[b.XXX],[d.XXX],[g.XXX]"
    NA',header=T)
```

De igual manera asumí que el resultado que persigues es el siguiente:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 7
  id_rep `[a.XXX]` `[b.XXX]` `[c.XXX]` `[h.XXX]` `[d.XXX]` `[g.XXX]`
   <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1      1         1         1         1         0         0         0
2      2         0         0         1         1         0         0
3      3         1         1         0         0         1         1
4      4        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

**Nota:** MVC te dejo el siguiente código tratando el problema que he entendido. Pero quizá entendí mal, si es así házmelo saber en un comentario.

Lo primero que note al atacar el problema es que los datos no tienen un identificador de respondiente, supuse que es un respondiente por fila y comencé por crear un identificador único por respondiente `id_rep`. He tratado de explicar el resto de los pasos como comentarios en el siguiente código:

```
#Crear un id del respondiente
df$id_rep<-1:nrow(df)

#Separar var1 en distintas variables
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#Separamos solo los que no tienen NA en var1
df1<-df[!is.na(df$var1),]
#Creamos un data freme con solo el id_rep de los que tienen NA en var1
df2<-df[is.na(df$var1),]%>%select(id_rep)

df1<-df1%>%
    #Separamos las respuestas del respondiente por comas,
    #En 6 variables auxiliares a,b,c... he tomado 6 pues entinedo
    #pues entiendo que un respondiente puede tener un maximo de 6
    #respuestas, cambiese si esto no es asi
    separate(var1,sep=',',into=letters[1:6])%>%
    #Pasamos las respuestas a formato largo
    pivot_longer(!id_rep,names_to='value',values_to='name')%>%
    #Sustituimos por 1 el valor de la respuesta
    mutate(value=1)%>%
    #Filtramos aquellas respuestas con NA 
    #(es decir aquellas que no selecciono el respondiente x)
    filter(!is.na(name))%>%
    #Pasamos a formato largo
    pivot_wider()

#Remplazamos los NA por 0
df1[is.na(df1)]<-0
df1

#Agregamos los id_rep que no respondieron nada
df1<-bind_rows(df1,df2)
df1
```

Answer (score 0):

Usar `str_detect()` es una buena opción, el problema es que se espera un patrón de expresión regular para buscar, y lo cierto es que la cadena que estás buscando, `"[a.XXX])"`, no es un patrón válido. Los paréntesis, los corchetes y el punto són códigos especiales de la expresión regular, si lo que quieres es buscar el caracter literal, debes "escapear" el código:

```
str_detect(df$var1,"\\[a\\.XXX\\]")
```

La doble barra invertida sirve para esto, con `\\[` estas diciendo que se debe buscar el literal `[`, igual que con `\\.`. Toma nota que he quitado el paréntesis por que no corresponde al menos con el ejemplo que has dado.

Ejemplo:

```
df$v_a <- str_detect(df$var1,"\\[a\\.XXX\\]")
df$v_b <- str_detect(df$var1,"\\[b\\.XXX\\]")
df$v_c <- str_detect(df$var1,"\\[c\\.XXX\\]")
df$v_d <- str_detect(df$var1,"\\[d\\.XXX\\]")
df$v_e <- str_detect(df$var1,"\\[e\\.XXX\\]")
df$v_h <- str_detect(df$var1,"\\[f\\.XXX\\]")
df$v_i <- str_detect(df$var1,"\\[i\\.XXX\\]")
df$v_g <- str_detect(df$var1,"\\[g\\.XXX\\]")

df

                             var1   v_a   v_b   v_c   v_d   v_e   v_h   v_i   v_g
1         [a.XXX],[b.XXX],[c.XXX]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2                 [c.XXX],[h.XXX] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3 [a.XXX],[b.XXX],[d.XXX],[g.XXX]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
4                            <NA>    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Seguramente hay formas más genéricas de resolverlo, pero tendría que ver bien el formato real que tienes, por que me da la impresión que los que has dado es más bien un ejemplo.